# Getting "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer" when tried with https request from android app using loopj

Tags: android, google-app-engine, ssl, android-async-http

I am using google app engine as backend, and had proper ssl certificates installed/added and DNS mapping is done by CNAME configurations. Everything is working fine expect in android app.

Throwing "javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer" error when an https request is made. And in android app loopj - ASyncHttpClient is used.

Even for the subdomain www.example.com, the ssl enabled for SNI+VIP.